# How to halt a Capistrano deploy from within a task

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have a task that validates the integrity of the build that is about to be deployed.

I would like to halt/fail the deploy in case it's broken.

```
task :test_build do
  if something
    puts "Problem with build"
    #prevent deploy to continue further
  end
end
after('deploy:update_code', 'test_build')
```

Note: Project uses `railsless-deploy`

Comment: `raise` should work for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should raise a CommandError exception:

```
error = CommandError.new("An error that should abort and rollback deployment") 
raise error
```

So no backtrace are shown.

Answer (score 1):

CommandError is no longer defined in Capistrano.  Looking at other examples, I found that using puts statements describing the error followed by an exit call are being used.  So just:

```
puts "Problem with build"
exit
```

Comment: This has the behavior I want, but using exit in a rails app is frowned upon: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rails/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/rails/exit.rb

Comment: @lucas You are correct.  I think that this is not technically in the Rails app, since it is only in the Capistrano deployment.  It isn't as elegant as I would like though.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @engineersmnky in the question's comments, `raise "Error with build"` will trigger a halt for the current deploy. But this solution print an ugly stack trace since it's not handled by Capistrano.